# Efficiently sending many HTTP requests to the same server from same client

Tags: java, rest, http, asynchronous, httpurlconnection

I currently have an application that generates a huge amount of data and sends it to various REST endpoints (different paths) periodically. At the moment, in my application, each data point for each path uses a new `HttpURLConnection` object, so I imagine that this will not scale well as a new connection object needs to be created very often, even though they are all pointing to the same destination address.

Is there a good application/library I can use to send all of these (perhaps asynchronously)? The key point here is that they are all being sent to the same address. The application I am creating is a service, so it will be running "forever" in a server and constantly making connections.

Edit: I have thought about just using the same connection object but I've not only seen issues with that online, but also do not want to deal with issues (yet) regarding connection loss, etc. Ideally, I'm searching for a library that takes care of the overhead.

Comment: Are you asking us to recommend a library or a tool ?

Comment: @alfasin I'm not sure what the difference is, so I'm going to say either. I'm just looking for something that will help me efficiently deal with this, without having to go through the overhead myself.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at using Ruby Rake tasks and CRON job's? You are asking for opinions so you are likely going to get down voted and question closed so I thought I'd just chuck this in while you have a chance to read it. Good luck

Comment: @jamesc Thanks for the help. I am looking for something purely within Java (so not running through an external shell or script). Also, just to clarify, I am not necessarily asking for opinions but suggestions on libraries/tools that deal with this, as I have not come across anything similar in my search.

Comment: Well it's my opinion that the java app should dump the data to a database and a background cron job can run with a rake task that can pick the data up from the database and chuck it out to the relevant url end points. I would consider that to be the best tool for the job. http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do nothing. Write your normal code. `HttpURLConnection` does connection pooling behind the scenes, via HTTP Keep-alive.

NB You send requests *from* clients, and *to* servers.

Comment: So say I am sending a burst of requests every second or so. Is this short enough to still keep using the connection pooling, or will new underlying connections still be made? I realize this may not be known due to unknown underlying implementation.

Comment: Almost certainly. I believe the idle timeout is at least fifteen seconds.